# How to add Dynamic Rows Component to my custom module?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I developed site in magento 2. i create a custom module. now i want to add Dynamic Rows Component to my module i read document.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui-components/ui_dynamic_rows.html

But i know magento at beginner level. and i can't able to understand after reading document. i can't understand where on which file should i changed.

Answer (score 2):

I give you idea how you can do it not whole answer.
You create DataProvider in your module this is sample code

```
protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder) {
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'addButtonLabel' => __('Add Value'),
                    'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows',
                    'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                    'deleteProperty' => static::FIELD_IS_DELETE,
                    'deleteValue' => '1',
                    'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [
            'record' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                            'positionProvider' => static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME,
                            'isTemplate' => true,
                            'is_collection' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children' => [
                    static::FIELD_CUSTOM_NAME => $this->getCustomFieldConfig(10)

                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
protected function getCustomFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = []) {
    return array_replace_recursive(
        [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Test'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_CUSTOM_NAME,
                    'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        ], $options
    );
}
```

for more detail please check following file 
Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions.php

Comment: how can we limit the dynamic rows? i need to set max 10.