# How to create a simple Dynamic rows in admin using Data Provider?

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

Can anyone please show me an example of creating dynamic rows using **"Data Provider"** in Magento 2, like the Tire price creations in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: http://blog.belvg.com/dynamic-settings-array-in-magento-2-0.html
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128384/how-to-add-dynamic-rows-component-to-my-custom-module
http://www.thienphucvx.com/magento-2-knockout-js-simple-module/
Not able to find Magento 2 Docs link. If any one find then please share. Please refer `magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing.php`. Not able to get perfect answer

Comment: @AnkitShah Thanks for the replay. Is there any way to do it with out using Dataprovider?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Dynamic Rows Component to my custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128384/how-to-add-dynamic-rows-component-to-my-custom-module)

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara, is there any way we can set maximum rows for Dynamic rows, I just need to limit to 10

Comment: complete dynamic row with xml and meta methods for product page

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/magento-2-creating-dynamic-matrix-in-new-edit-product-page/357525#357525

Answer (score 2):

Below I have added works **Dynamic Rows** functionality as an extension. You can copy it and customize it to your needs.

You can check code in my repo [here](https://github.com/bbakalovGlobal/Bss_DynamicRows/).  
Description and how extension works you can find [here](https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/ui-components-how-to-use-dynamicrows-components-in-magento-2/).

Comment: You should copy relevant information from the links into your answer in case of link rot.

Comment: Do you think I should maintain the repo based on the data from the article? I don't think so.
I just provided a working example for Dynamic Rows, anybody can install it and test it. It's not an extension that anybody recommends using in production, just a sample that is provided for development purposes.

Comment: No offense intended, just a suggestion from the policy: “Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.” (https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for this reference to the policy. But I still don't understand what the issue is. 
I refactored that code and added some fixes, so the description, in general, is still actual, but the code base has been changed a little bit, based on the Magento best practices.

Comment: It’s a valuable resource no doubt about that. My suggestion, based on the policy, is just to _also_ quote the most important concepts in the answer here. It can be updated in light of new best practices too. Thanks for contributing!