# Magento 2: Creating dynamic matrix in new/edit product page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, uicomponent

I need to create a custom matrix for every product on Magento 2 product add/edit page. I need to have both the rows and columns to be dynamic so when someone click add button for either row or column there should be a row or column created depending upon his choice.

I tried to find solution for my problem but I don't think Magento 2 supports anything like this however we can only add dynamic rows in Magento 2 but not Dynamic columns either.

So I decided to create a custom block on product page to use third-party extension for achieving my goal and then serializing the matrix data when the **save** button on product page is clicked and append it to form data somehow and get in my observer/plugin and process it according to my need.

Problems:

- I tried to add a custom block in Magento 2 product page by [this](https://webkul.com/blog/add-tab-product-page-magento-admin/comment-page-1) article but I couldn't see that it's rendered on the page (may be some xml related stuff is updated in M2.2).
- Is there really a way we can do so with Magento2? If no then please suggest me how can I add custom block on product page and how to link the matrix data with product form so when I submit it it can be captured on back-end.

Comment: Hi Umar, Have you figured how to add dynamic rows ? please share if you have done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. Here is how we can add dynamic rows to Product Edit Page:

Add DataProvider class as:

**etc\adminhtml\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
<arguments>
    <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="customTab" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NewField</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

And add DataProvider at:

**Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier:**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
class NewField extends AbstractModifier
{
const FIELD_IS_DELETE = 'is_delete';
const FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME = 'sort_order';
const FIELD_NAME_SELECT = 'select_field';

private $locator;
public function __construct(
LocatorInterface $locator
) {
$this->locator = $locator;
}
public function modifyData(array $data)
 {
return $data;
}
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
 $meta = array_replace_recursive(
    $meta,
    [
        'custom_fieldset' => [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom Group'),
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'data.product.custom_fieldset',
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'sortOrder' => 5,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
"custom_field" => $this->getSelectTypeGridConfig(10)
],
        ]
    ]
);
return $meta;
}
protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder) {
return [
'arguments' => [
    'data' => [
        'config' => [
            'addButtonLabel' => __('Add Value'),
            'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows',
            'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
            'deleteProperty' => static::FIELD_IS_DELETE,
            'deleteValue' => '1',
            'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
        ],
    ],
],
'children' => [
    'record' => [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                    'positionProvider' => static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME,
                    'isTemplate' => true,
                    'is_collection' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [
            static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT => $this->getSelectFieldConfig(1),
            static::FIELD_IS_DELETE => $this->getIsDeleteFieldConfig(3)
            //Add as many fields as you want

        ]
    ]
]
];
}
protected function getSelectFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
return [
    'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
                'label' => __('Options Select'),
                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/custom-options-type',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                // 'selectType' => 'optgroup',
                'dataScope' => static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT,
                'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                'options' => $this->_getOptions(),
                'visible' => true,
                'disabled' => false,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
}
protected function _getOptions()
{
$options = [
    1 => [
        'label' => __('Option 1'),
        'value' => 1
    ],
    2 => [
        'label' => __('Option 2'),
        'value' => 2
    ],
    3 => [
        'label' => __('Option 3'),
        'value' => 3
    ],
];

return $options;
}
protected function getIsDeleteFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
return [
    'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
                'componentType' => ActionDelete::NAME,
                'fit' => true,
                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
}
}
```

Comment: @ajawad, I need this, i was searching for same. May i know how to save this in database?

Comment: @Amitkumarsolanki did you find out how to save in database?

Answer (score 2):

**-> 'discount_frequency' create new product attribute as 'textarea' from admin and assign to attribute set**

BELOW CODE TO CREATE DYNAMIC ROW FOR text, textarea, dropdown select, wysiwyg HTML editor **

-> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="discountFrequency" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">VENDOR\MODULE\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Frequency</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>     
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>   
</config>
```

-> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Frequency.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\StockDataFilter;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Textarea;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;


class Frequency extends AbstractModifier
{
    const DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_FIELD = 'discount_frequency'; //attribute code

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    private $locator;

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    private $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $meta = [];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $scopeName;   

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        $scopeName = ''
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $fieldCode = self::DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_FIELD;

        $model = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $modelId = $model->getId();

        $frequencyData = $model->getDiscountFrequency();

        if ($frequencyData) {
            $frequencyData = json_decode($frequencyData, true);
            $path = $modelId . '/' . self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT . '/'. self::DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_FIELD;
            $data = $this->arrayManager->set($path, $data, $frequencyData);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this -> initDiscountFrequencyFields();
        return $this->meta;
    }


    protected function initDiscountFrequencyFields()
    {
        $frequencyPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(
            self::DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_FIELD,
            $this->meta,
            null,
            'children'
        );

        if ($frequencyPath) {
            $this->meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                $frequencyPath,
                $this->meta,
                $this->initFrquencyFieldStructure($frequencyPath)
            );
            $this->meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
                $this->arrayManager->slicePath($frequencyPath, 0, -3)
                . '/' . self::DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_FIELD,
                $this->meta,
                $this->arrayManager->get($frequencyPath, $this->meta)
            );
            $this->meta = $this->arrayManager->remove(
                $this->arrayManager->slicePath($frequencyPath, 0, -2),
                $this->meta
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }   


    protected function initFrquencyFieldStructure($frequencyPath)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => 'dynamicRows',
                        'label' => __('Discount Frequency'),
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'dndConfig' => [
                            'enabled' => false,
                        ],
                        'disabled' => false,
                        'sortOrder' =>
                            $this->arrayManager->get($frequencyPath . '/arguments/data/config/sortOrder', $this->meta),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'dataScope' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'discount' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                        'label' => __('Discount percentage'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'discount',
                                        'require' => '1',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'frequency' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'formElement' => Textarea::NAME,
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                        'label' => __('Frequency'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'frequency',
                                        'require' => '1',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'frequency_type' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                        'label' => __('Frequency Type'),
                                        'dataScope' => 'frequency_type',
                                        'options' => $this->FrequencyType(),
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        // ONLY FOR 'wysiwyg' HTML Editor FIELD USE THIS FIELD

                        // 'value' => [
                        //     'arguments' => [
                        //         'data' => [
                        //             'config' => [
                        //                 'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        //                 'formElement' => 'wysiwyg',
                        //                 'wysiwygConfigData' => [
                        //                     'height' => '100px',
                        //                     'add_variables' => true,
                        //                     'add_widgets' => true,
                        //                     'add_images' => true,
                        //                     'add_directives' => true,
                        //                     'dynamic_id' => true,
                        //                 ],
                        //                 'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        //                 'label' => __('Value'),
                        //                 'enableLabel' => true,
                        //                 'dataScope' => 'value',
                        //                 'sortOrder' => 30,
                        //                 'validation' => [
                        //                     'required-entry' => true,
                        //                 ],
                        //             ],
                        //         ],
                        //     ],
                        // ],                         
                        'actionDelete' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                        'label' => '',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function FrequencyType()
    {
        $regionOptions = array();
        $regionOptions[] = ['label' =>  'Month', 'value' => 1];
        $regionOptions[] = ['label' =>  'Week', 'value' => 2];
        $regionOptions[] = ['label' =>  'Year', 'value' => 3];
        return $regionOptions;
    }
}
?>
```

-> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">     
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer name="discount_frequency_save_before" instance="VENDOR\MODULE\Observer\SerializedDiscountFrequency" />
    </event>
</config>
```

-> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Observer/SerializedDiscountFrequency.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SerializedDiscountFrequency implements ObserverInterface
{
    const ATTR_DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_CODE = 'discount_frequency'; //attribute code

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
        $post = $this->request->getPost();
        $post = $post['product'];
        $frequencyData = isset($post[self::ATTR_DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_CODE]) ? $post[self::ATTR_DISCOUNT_FREQUENCY_CODE] : '';
        $product->setDiscountFrequency($frequencyData);
        $requiredParams = ['discount','frequency']; // PARAMS you defined in Frequency.php file
        if (is_array($frequencyData)) {
            $frequencyData = $this->removeEmptyArray($frequencyData, $requiredParams);
            $product->setDiscountFrequency(json_encode($frequencyData));
        }
    }

    private function removeEmptyArray($discountData, $requiredParams) {
        $requiredParams = array_combine($requiredParams, $requiredParams);
        $reqCount = count($requiredParams);

        foreach ($discountData as $key => $values) {
            $values = array_filter($values);
            $inersectCount = count(array_intersect_key($values, $requiredParams));
            if ($reqCount != $inersectCount) {
                unset($discountData[$key]);
            }  
        }
        return $discountData;
    }
}
```

-> remove generated and flush cache

The above will generate
[image]

---

**ALTERNATE METHOD:**

**-> only create this file and it will save the data automatically
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml**

-> 'discount_frequency' is attribute name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <dataSource name="product_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider"
                      name="product_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    
    <!--Here discount_frequency is attribute name-->
    <fieldset sortOrder="50" name="discount_frequency">
        <settings>
            <label>Fieldset label</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>

            <!--Here discount_frequency is attribute name-->
             <dataScope>data.product.discount_frequency</dataScope>    
        </settings>

        <dynamicRows name="dynamic_row">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add</addButtonLabel>
                <additionalClasses>
                    <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                </additionalClasses>
                <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
                <elementTmpl>ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid</elementTmpl>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="'positionProvider'" xsi:type="string">container_option</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>

                <field name="title" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <label translate="true">Title</label>
                        <dataScope>title</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>

                <field name="value" formElement="wysiwyg" sortOrder="40">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="dynamic_id" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <label translate="true">Value</label>
                        <dataScope>value</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                    <formElements>
                        <wysiwyg class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                            <settings>
                                <rows>8</rows>
                                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                            </settings>
                        </wysiwyg>
                    </formElements>
                </field>

                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This a great example of dynamic rows