# Magento 2 DynamicRow not working properly in Admin Product Edit Page

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.4, dynamic-rows

I'm trying to add dynamic rows in the product edit page in adminhtml. I'm using Magento 2.3.4. I have successfully added a dynamic row but the problem is the 'Add' button is not working after one row is inserted. Also, it is not giving any error in the console. But I notice that when I click 'Delete' button on the first row,  it is also giving error 'Cannot set property 'delete' of undefined' at line no 858 in dynamic-rows.js

Below is my code.

In di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="product_feature_new" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">
                    Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Feature
                </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
</config>
```

DataProvider class Feature.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface;

class Feature implements ModifierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * Feature constructor.
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    )
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta =  array_merge_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                'feature_product' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                      'data' => [
                          'config' => [
                              'componentType' => 'dynamicRows',
                              'label' => __('Custom FieldSet'),
                              'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                              'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                              'dataScope' => '',
                              'dndConfig' => [
                                  'enabled' => false,
                              ],
                              'required' => false,
                              'sortOrder' => 1000,
                              'addButton' => true,
                              'addButtonLabel' => 'Add New Record',
                              'deleteValue' => true,
                          ],
                      ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'record' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                        'isTemplate' => true,
                                        'is_collection' => true,
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                        'dataScope' => '',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            'children' => [
                                'feature' => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                                'label' => __('Feature'),
                                                'dataScope' => 'feature',
                                                'sortOrder' => 10,
                                                'validation' => [
                                                    'required-entry' => true,
                                                    'validate-greater-than-zero' => true,
                                                    'validate-digits' => false,
                                                    'validate-number' => true,
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                                'actionDelete' => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                                                'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                                'label' => 'Actions',
                                                'sortOrder' => 20,
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }

}
```

Can anybody tell me if I miss anything? or any correction needed to make it work?

Comment: have you got any solutions for this issue because as I am also facing the same issue in product form.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed datascope for your custom fieldset. The dynamic rows working with link property, which is need a proper datascope to add records.

Try the below code:

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta =  array_merge_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                'feature_product' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                      'data' => [
                          'config' => [
                              'componentType' => 'dynamicRows',
                              'label' => __('Custom FieldSet'),
                              'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                              'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                              'dataScope' => 'data.product.feature_product', //You have missed this datascope
                              'dndConfig' => [
                                  'enabled' => false,
                              ],
                              'required' => false,
                              'sortOrder' => 1000,
                              'addButton' => true,
                              'addButtonLabel' => 'Add New Record',
                              'deleteValue' => true,
                          ],
                      ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'record' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                        'isTemplate' => true,
                                        'is_collection' => true,
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                        'dataScope' => '',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            'children' => [
                                'feature' => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                                'label' => __('Feature'),
                                                'dataScope' => 'feature',
                                                'sortOrder' => 10,
                                                'validation' => [
                                                    'required-entry' => true,
                                                    'validate-greater-than-zero' => true,
                                                    'validate-digits' => false,
                                                    'validate-number' => true,
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                                'actionDelete' => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                                                'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                                'label' => 'Actions',
                                                'sortOrder' => 20,
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        return $meta;
    }
```

Please refer more information from the answers:

[Magento 2 - Unable to add record in dynamic rows in admin product edit page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336825/magento-2-unable-to-add-record-in-dynamic-rows-in-admin-product-edit-page/337081#337081)

[Magento 2: Creating dynamic matrix in new/edit product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/magento-2-creating-dynamic-matrix-in-new-edit-product-page/272729#272729)

Hope it will help others!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please used this i thought 'formElement' is missing

```
            public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
            {
                $meta =  array_merge_recursive(
                    $meta,
                    [
                        'feature_product' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                              'data' => [
                                  'config' => [
                                      'componentType' => 'dynamicRows',
                                      'formElement' => 'component',
                                      'label' => __('Custom FieldSet'),
                                      'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                                      'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                                      'dataScope' => '',
                                      'dndConfig' => [
                                          'enabled' => false,
                                      ],
                                      'required' => false,
                                      'sortOrder' => 1000,
                                      'addButton' => true,
                                      'addButtonLabel' => 'Add New Record',
                                      'deleteValue' => true,
                                  ],
                              ],
                            ],
                            'children' => [
                                'record' => [
                                    'arguments' => [
                                        'data' => [
                                            'config' => [
                                                'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                                'is_collection' => true,
                                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                                'dataScope' => '',
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                    'children' => [
                                        'feature' => [
                                            'arguments' => [
                                                'data' => [
                                                    'config' => [
                                                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                                        'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                                                        'label' => __('Feature'),
                                                        'dataScope' => 'feature',
                                                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                                                        'validation' => [
                                                            'required-entry' => true,
                                                            'validate-greater-than-zero' => true,
                                                            'validate-digits' => false,
                                                            'validate-number' => true,
                                                        ],
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                        'actionDelete' => [
                                            'arguments' => [
                                                'data' => [
                                                    'config' => [
                                                        'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                                                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                                                        'label' => 'Actions',
                                                        'sortOrder' => 20,
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                );
                return $meta;
            }
```