# Show Multiple Quantity + Product Price on Product Detail Page in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.2, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4

How we can show quantity table + product prices as given below screenshot on product Detail Page. If someone have idea, Please guide me i want to implement like this. These prices should be change according to variations.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use dynamic row component where you can set quantity , price and shipping option on admin  product edit .

Refer below link
[Magento 2: Creating dynamic matrix in new/edit product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/magento-2-creating-dynamic-matrix-in-new-edit-product-page)

On product after save event you can save all values into your separate database table and get it on product detail page.

On product detail page you can write js on selection of quantity to set total quantity to be purchase and Change price after product added into cart and update cart event.

Make sure that cart qty restriction should be consider in your logic.

Thanks
Amit