# In dynamic rows wysiwyg editor field not properly delete in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dynamic-rows, editor

When I added 2 or multiple dynamic rows and then delete the first row the 1st-row editor field was not deleted.

check below images

```
Before delete
```

[image]

**`After delete 1st row`**
[image]

The 1st-row editor value should be thereafter deleting the 1st-row but the input field is deleted.

my UI-component code

```
  <fieldset name="dynamic_rows_set">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">FAQ Section</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="dynamic_rows_container">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/dynamic-rows/templates/default</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                    <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">record</item>
                    <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add Row</item>
                    <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="admin__field-wide" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <container name="record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dynamic Rows</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record
                        </item>
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>

                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="entity_id">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <!--<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="question">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                            <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="answer" formElement="wysiwyg" sortOrder="40">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="dynamic_id" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <label translate="true">Answer</label>
                        <dataScope>answer</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                    <formElements>
                        <wysiwyg class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                            <settings>
                                <rows>8</rows>
                                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                            </settings>
                        </wysiwyg>
                    </formElements>
                </field>
                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Does anyone, please help me with this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/magento-2-creating-dynamic-matrix-in-new-edit-product-page/357525#357525

Comment: please check your observer that fill changes, it is helped me to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed `<item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>` TO `<item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

it's working for me.